# Azure Service Bus Topic Architecture

Tags: c#, azure, microservices, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I've been working through the [eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers) project provided by Microsoft, honing my microservice skills in general. One of the big concepts is the introduction of an Event Bus. I've opted to try it with Azure Service Bus but my experience with the platform is limited.

I've managed to get the project running after manually creating the Topics, Subscriptions, etc, but this raises a few questions:

Is it not the responsibility of the subscribing application to create it's own Subscription in Azure? e.g. on startup?

Conceptually, Topics represent different event stacks, correct? E.g. Customers, Ordering, etc? Or are they intended to be domain event boundaries? E.g. in this application, 'eShop' would be the topic.

Azure deployments is a whole other topic, but related to the Service Bus configuration, are there any recommended techniques for managing that within source control?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend u to have a look at Azure management fluent api https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net

Comment: Ah, a potential missing link. I couldn't find the .NET Core varieties of this previously. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it not the responsibility of the subscribing application to create it's own Subscription in Azure? e.g. on startup?

That's correct. The details depend on the underlying messaging service you're using. In case of Azure Service Bus, each service upon startup will subscribe to the events it's interested in. For example, `Ordering` will [subscribe during startup to the events it handles](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.API/Startup.cs#L254). The project has a [`IEventBusSubscriptionsManager` contract](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBus/IEventBusSubscriptionsManager.cs) to be implemented specifically for each messaging service. For [Azure Service Bus implementation](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusServiceBus/EventBusServiceBus.cs) each service has a physical subscription and each event its interested in is represented by a rule, filtering messages by the value of Service Bus message `Label` (`Label` contains event name).

> Conceptually, Topics represent different event stacks, correct? E.g. Customers, Ordering, etc? Or are they intended to be domain event boundaries? E.g. in this application, 'eShop' would be the topic

Topics are the points of fanning messages out. You could use a topic per service, but that would mean subscribers would need to know what service is publishing those events. Alternatively, and potentially better option is to have *a topic* that is known by all of your services, and publish events to that topic. Call it "`Events`" for now. Each service interested in various events would create a subscription. A subscription would be able to get *any* message (event) published to `Events` topic, but really should only "catch" and deliver events it needs (read "subscribed to"). That's where filtering is coming in. By creating filters (`RuleDescription`s) a given subscription for each services declares on the broker what messages it will receive.

> Azure deployments is a whole other topic, but related to the Service Bus configuration, are there any recommended techniques for managing that within source control?

A few options.

1. Code-based creation of entities at at run-time (topics, subscriptions with rules, queues).
2. Capture topology with ARM templates and version just like code in version control system.
3. Use [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest) and version control your scripts.

Comment: @jeremy-smith there's [another variant](https://github.com/Particular/eShopOnContainers) of this project that is using NServiceBus and Particular Platform. With the platform offering visualization and messaging debugging tools, you can see message flow and easily wire a transport (messaging service) of your choice.  You can try that one to see if it makes things a bit easier.

Comment: from what I can tell, the `Subscribe()` ([here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusServiceBus/EventBusServiceBus.cs#L78)) implementation just adds a `RuleDescription` to an _existing_ Azure Subscription...what am I missing?

Comment: I always try to explain to people that a topic is like a webhook: you can subscribe to speicifc event/message. EventGrid do the same but use Http rather than bus messaging

Comment: @JeremySmith correct, but there's no subscription manager implementaiton for ASB, which makes it weird (read incomplete?)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the feedback, I was able to able to throw together a crude solution based on the eShop [Event Bus](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusServiceBus/EventBusServiceBus.cs) to create the Azure Subscriptions upon startup:

```
 public EventBusServiceBus(IServiceBusPersisterConnection serviceBusPersisterConnection,
        ILogger<EventBusServiceBus> logger, IEventBusSubscriptionsManager subsManager, string subscriptionClientName,
        ILifetimeScope autofac, AzureUserCredentials userCredentials, string subscriptionId, string resourceGroupName, string serviceBusName, string topicName)
    {
        _serviceBusPersisterConnection = serviceBusPersisterConnection;
        _logger = logger;
        _subsManager = subsManager ?? new InMemoryEventBusSubscriptionsManager();

        _subscriptionClient = new Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.SubscriptionClient(serviceBusPersisterConnection.ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder,
            subscriptionClientName);
        _autofac = autofac;

        var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(
          userCredentials.ClientId, userCredentials.ClientSecret, userCredentials.TenantId, AzureEnvironment.FromName(userCredentials.EnvironmentName));

        var azure = Azure
                .Configure()
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .Authenticate(credentials)
                .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

        var nm = azure.ServiceBusNamespaces.GetByResourceGroup(resourceGroupName, serviceBusName);

        var topic = nm.Topics.GetByName(topicName);

        if (topic == null)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Topic {topic} does not exist.", nameof(topic));

        Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent.ISubscription subscription = null;
        try
        { subscription = topic.Subscriptions.GetByName(subscriptionClientName); }
        catch { }

        if (subscription == null)
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"Creating Azure Subscription '{subscriptionClientName}'");
            topic.Subscriptions.Define(subscriptionClientName).WithDeleteOnIdleDurationInMinutes(5).Create();
        }
        else
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"Azure Subscription '{subscriptionClientName}' already exists. Reusing.");
        }

        RemoveDefaultRule();
        RegisterSubscriptionClientMessageHandler();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Sean Feldman also mentioned about having a single topic as the central channel to publish messages, if you are also keying about the performance of having single topic verses multiple topics, see this performance guideline provided by azure docs. I quoted the most interesting part that would help you.

> From a scalability perspective, there really isn't too much of a difference that you would notice as Service Bus already spreads the load across multiple logs internally, so if you use six queues or topics or two queues or topics won't make a material difference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2#multiple-queues-or-topics

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34114128)